# Bash Script: find command getting stuck

Tags: bash

I'm currently writing a bash script wherein a portion of it needs to be able to look at a bunch of directory hierarchies and spit out two text files each containing a list of the directories and all the files, respectively, in the given directory.

As I understand the following should do the trick:

```
find $directory -type d >> alldirs.txt
```

where directory is assigned different directory path names since I'm supposed to check a number of them.

I have a for loop the iterates through my list of directories and uses the above function to complete my task. The above command gets to a certain point and then it gets stuck. When I investigated the issue it seemed like it would get to a directory that's empty and then it get stuck. And or it would actually start looking for directories that don't exist in the first place then it would get stuck. Any ideas?

Is there something I'm missing? Or did I understand how that works incorrectly? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Since it's "stuck in a loop", I think posting the actual loop code would help a lot.

Comment: I updated my question. I checked my loop and its not the loop itself, but rather specifically the find command. I tried it out on a single directory hierarchy (outside of a for loop) and I ran into the same problem

Comment: Is something mounted in the directory where it gets stuck? Like a FUSE fs or network directory?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Although one of the directories I'm looking through a file system thats mounted as read only

Comment: Don't think this is your problem in the particular case, but you should quote `"$directory"` to prevent future issues.

Comment: What are you passing as `$directory`? If you are passing something line `/lib` or `/lib64`, you can expect a significant wait. Post your loop and how you are feeding names to `$directory`. Without it, it is just a guess of the possible reason.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said $directory is a name.  Without it, bash will complain that "find: $directory: No such file or directory"

For example:

```
find . -iname $directory -type d >> alldirs.txt
```

Note: The above will start searching in the current directory, specified by the "."

Change it to whatever directory you wish e.g. /home/mys.celeste

Comment: I tried this out and it didn't make a difference. Still does the same thing.

Comment: Well post the entire script up :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue: `find / -name blahblah` stuck somewhere
When debugging I tried to search in all root directories like`/tmp, /var, /sbin, /user` and so on. And found that it is stuck on /media.
In `/media` I had `RHEL` repo mounted. So after`unmount - find` continue to work normally.